# Parse Indian currency from string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, currency

I want to parse last indian currency ie Rs from a string.

For example:

1. Price for this item is Rs. 100   --> 100
2. Price for this item is Rs. 100 to Rs. 120 --> 120
3. Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to Rs. 125.4 --> 125.4
4. Price for this item is Rs. 100 to Rs. invalid_price --> 100
5. Price for this item is Rs. 100 to 125 --> 100, not 125 cause 125 is having Rs. in front of it.

Rs. or Rs both will be fine. I want to get number prepended with Rs. or Rs

How can I parse this string.

Comment: Do you always want the rightmost number?

Comment: I was going to suggest using the Money gem (https://github.com/collectiveidea/money), but it doesn't appear to support Rs, to my surprise. It's very US-centric.

Comment: @d11wtq I am just looking for parsing a string. Why i need a gem of that. Moreover money gem is to covert into string into currency. I dont want to covert to currency. Check the question again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goal is get the rightmost occurance of:

- The text "Rs"
- Optional abbreviation period "."
- A space
- Digits and optionally a decimal point and more digits

Solution:

```
s = "Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to 125.4"
s.scan(/Rs.? (\d+\.\d+|\d+)/).last
#=> 102.2

s = "Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to Rs. 125.4"
s.scan(/Rs.? (\d+\.\d+|\d+)/).last
#=> 125.4
```

Comment: this is having issue like: s = "Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to 125.4" will return 125.4 but in that case i want 100.2

Comment: @MohitJain Not according to your example above. _Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to Rs. 125.4 --> 125.4_

Comment: Your question says that  "Price for this item is Rs. 100.2 to 125.4" --> 125.4  (or can you explain more about what you want?)

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson added cases in the question. please check it.

Comment: Upgraded for new cases in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like

`price = "Price for item is Rs. 100".scan(/(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/).flatten.last`

The `scan` method returns an array containing all the matched numbers (because of the `\d+`). And side you always want the last found *real* number (statement four) you in fact want the last element in the array.

This will also allow for case #3, where you have floats.

Comment: Joelparkhenderson's solution is more elegant, as it takes into consideration the "Rs" part of the currency.